# Delete file in multiple directories on remote server using SSH

Tags: shell, ssh

I have written a script to delete files on a remote server. There are multiple directories and the script moves to each directory and finds the file older than the defined time and deletes it. But if the script finds the files to delete, it deletes them and comes out of the while loop.

input: directory list file which has the list of directories and the file name.

Below is the code.

```
MsgLog " Step 1: Start checking directories for old logs"
cat $DIRECTORY_LIST | while read DIR;
do
read LOG_FILE
read LOG_RET_PERIOD

MsgLog "Inputs"
MsgLog "Server=$SERVER User=$USER Log_path=$DIR Log_file=$LOG_FILE Log_Retention_Period=$LOG_RET_PERIOD"

                ssh -q -n -o 'BatchMode yes' $USER@$SERVER "cd $DIR;find $LOG_FILE* -mtime +$LOG_RET_PERIOD" >>$FIND_log

                ERROR_MSG=$?
                        if [ $ERROR_MSG -ne 0 ]
                        then
                                MsgLog "ERROR $ERROR_MSG: Could not connect."
                                exit 1
                        fi

                if [ -s "$FIND_log" ]
                        then
                        MsgLog "  Files to delete:"
                        cat $FIND_log
                        ssh $USER@$SERVER "cd $DIR;find $LOG_FILE* -mtime +$LOG_RET_PERIOD -exec rm {} \;"
                        ERROR_MSG=$?
                        if [ $ERROR_MSG -ne 0 ]
                        then
                                MsgLog "ERROR $ERROR_MSG: Step 1, Could not delete old Log Files."
                                exit 1
                        fi
                else
                        MsgLog "  No log files to delete."
                fi
        rm $FIND_log
        MsgLog "Move to next directory"
done
MsgLog "No more directories"

if [ "$EXIT_CODE" = 0 ]
then
  MsgLog "$BNAME successfully completed"
else
  MsgLog "$BNAME completed with errors"
fi

exit $EXIT_CODE
```

I want it to loop to all directories. But it exits the loop when it finds and deletes the files from any of the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the use of `read` at `cat $DIRECTORY_LIST | while read DIR`.

On certain implementations of `read`, particularly on RedHat derived distributions, `read` is a shell script and its output gets reset when the shell changes.

Since the shell changes every time `ssh` logs in to another host, the loop stops after the first `ssh` call.

Change the top loop to something that does not use `read`, for example:

```
for DIR in `cat $DIRECTORY_LIST`; do
<..>
done
```

Comment: But my directory list has path name in one line,file name in the next line and retention period in the next subsequent lines and so on. The file name and retention period changes for each file.

Comment: Then you will need to replace those uses of `read` with something else as well.

Comment: On the above, only if the value of `read` is being used in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I replaced all the the 'read' commands. it is working now!

Comment: Awesome, glad it works. Please accept the answer if it answered your question ;)